# Estou tendo problemas com scroll no JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Olá, eu estou utilizando a função scroll que tem no document do JQuery, tudo ocorre muito bem, pelo menos enquanto estou no componente que tem os href para fazer a rolagem, mas quando eu saio desse componente, obtenho o seguinte erro toda vez que faço uma rolagem: *ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined*

Componente da Navbar

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  // Navbar
  opacityNavbar: number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.animateScrolling();
    this.activeOpacityNavbar();
    this.activeNavbar();
  }

  onNavbar() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
  }

  animateScrolling() {
    $("a").on('click', function () {
      let select = $(this).attr("href");
      let positionAux = $(select).offset().top;
      let position: number;
      if (select == "#home") {
        position = 0;
      } else if (select == "#about") {
        position = positionAux - 73;
      } else if (select == "#services") {
        position = positionAux + 127;
      } else if (select == "#contact") {
        position = positionAux - 43;
      }
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: position }, 600);
    });
  }

  activeNavbar() {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var opacityNavbar = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (opacityNavbar >= ($("#home").offset().top) && opacityNavbar < ($("#about").offset().top) - 73) {
        $(".home-nav").addClass("active");
        $(".about-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".services-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".contact-nav").removeClass("active");
      } else if (opacityNavbar >= ($("#about").offset().top) - 80 && opacityNavbar < ($("#services").offset().top) + 127) {
        $(".home-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".about-nav").addClass("active");
        $(".services-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".contact-nav").removeClass("active");
      } else if (opacityNavbar > ($("#services").offset().top) + 126 && opacityNavbar < ($("#contact").offset().top) - 44) {
        $(".home-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".about-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".services-nav").addClass("active");
        $(".contact-nav").removeClass("active");
      } else if (opacityNavbar >= ($("#contact").offset().top) - 43) {
        $(".home-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".about-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".services-nav").removeClass("active");
        $(".contact-nav").addClass("active");
      }
    });
  }

  activeOpacityNavbar() {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var opacityNavbar = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (opacityNavbar > ($("#about").offset().top) - 40) {
        $(".navbar").addClass("opacity-navbar");
      } else {
        $(".navbar").removeClass("opacity-navbar");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Componente das seções para rolagem

```
<section id="navbar">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</section>

<section id="home">
  <app-home></app-home>
</section>

<section id="about">
  <app-about-me></app-about-me>
</section>

<section id="skills">
  <app-skills></app-skills>
</section>

<section id="services">
  <app-posts></app-posts>
</section>

<section id="contact">
  <app-contact></app-contact>
</section>

<section>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</section>
<app-flags></app-flags>
```

Componente que não faz parte das seções e onde recebo o erro

```
<div class="bg font">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card blue-card col-6">
            <br><br>
            <i class="fas fa-user-astronaut icon text-center"></i>
            <br><br>
            <h1 class="welcome text-center">SEJA BEM-VINDO <br> AO PAINEL ADMINISTRATIVO</h1>
            <img class="logo" src="src\assets\images\Logo Hunter (sem fundo e branco).png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="card pink-card col-6">
            <br><br>
            <i class="fas fa-space-shuttle icon text-center"></i>
            <br><br>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>USUÁRIO</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="email" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="credential" placeholder="Digite o usuário">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>SENHA</label>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="password"
                        class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Digite a senha">
                </div>
                <br><br><br>
                <div *ngIf="loading" class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <app-lds-facebook-blue></app-lds-facebook-blue>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button *ngIf="!loading" [disabled]="email == '' || password == ''" (click)="login()" type="button"
                    class="btn">CONECTAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal font-black" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="errorModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Não foi possível fazer log in</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h6>{{ error }}</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Rotas (app-routing.module.ts)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
  }, {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }, {
    path: 'access-denied',
    component: GuardsErrorComponent
  }, {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminMainComponent,
    canActivate: [GuardsService],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }, {
        path: 'home',
        component: AdminHomeComponent,
        canActivate: [GuardsService]
      }, {
        path: 'about',
        component: AdminAboutComponent,
        canActivate: [GuardsService]
      }, {
        path: 'posts',
        component: AdminProjectsComponent,
        canActivate: [GuardsService]
      },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'home', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'about', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'services', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'contact', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu arrumei o problema da seguinte forma, criei uma variável booleana para validar se eu estava no componente que deveria fazer o scroll ou não, ele é iniciada como true, pois sabemos que estou no componente e quando saímos do componente (utilizando o ngOnDestroy) atribuímos o valor false (já que não estamos mais no componente) e depois quando voltamos, alteramos para true novamente, segue a solução abaixo:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare let $: any;
var scroll = true;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})

ngOnInit() {
    this.animateScrolling();
    this.activeOpacityNavbar();
    this.activeNavbar();
    this.activeScroll();
  }

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    scroll = false;
  }

activeScroll() { 
    if (scroll == false) {
      scroll = true;
    }
  }
```